# What is the purpose of emplace() if we can use vector[1] = someInt?

Tags: c++

For example, consider this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.emplace(vec.begin(),1);
```

In this scenario, it will assign an int value of 1 at index 0 of the vector without copying anything.

But what if I choose to assign a value of 1 at index 0 like this:

```
vec[0] = 1;
```

I know, that in high level language I do not need to worry about these things but I guess there should be a huge difference between those two methods in C++, maybe it is faster of allocates less memory (as emplace does not copy a value and saves some memory).

Can you please give an explanation?

Comment: `emplace` constructs an object, `vec[0]` on an **empty** vector is just undefined behavior. Is it not enough reason to favor one over the other?

Comment: @StoryTeller So what could possibly go wrong with undefined behavior?

Comment: It becomes more meaningful when the object is more complicated than `int`. You can default-construct and copy `int` without issues, but that is not true for all types.

Comment: Not knowing whether your program runs correctly, incorrectly or just wipes you hard-drive clean is considered by some to be problematic.

Comment: @nwp now it makes sense for me, thank you. I guess the best practice would be just to use emplace.

Comment: @StoryTeller You have to keep in mind sometimes, just a little bit, that some people on this website are not that experienced in programming and you have to be a little bit (just a little bit) open-minded about it.

Comment: Had I been close minded I would have told you to go google what UB is. You can just ignore me if you don't appreciate the humor I choose to present it with.

Comment: You should try to use `emplace_back` if you are adding a new element to the end. otherwise `emplace(vec.begin(), foo)` is pretty bad in the sense that it will shift any trailing elements down by one (just like insert), so avoid it unless you are trying to insert an object infront. `emplace` vs (`insert` or `push_back`) wont make a difference for primitive types. emplace forwards the arguments to construct in-place. I agree with @StoryTeller though, you should RTFM before you ask the question. It just seems like you have used intellisense and just went straight to SO. Try cppreference.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `std::vector<int>` it doesn't make any noticeable difference. It matters when you are storing objects that are expensive to copy.

```
std::vector<my_type> vec;
my_type object(1);
vec.push_back(object); // 1
vec.emplace_back(1);   // 2
```

In line 1, the code **copies** an object into the vector. In line 2, it **constructs** the object in place. In both cases, an object gets constructed. In line 1 the object **also** gets copied; if you don't need to have the object hanging around, line 2 does less work.

Comment: Thank you, that explained everything. I guess it is also true for the "vector.insert()" ? As the object also gets copied and then constructed.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov there is a Move semantics where the object gets move instead of copied if the type supports it: `vec.push_back(std::move(object));`. The original local variable `object` is then left in a implementation defined state.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `operator[]` to grow a vector. You must use one of `insert`, `emplace`, `push_back` or `emplace_back` to add an element. you can also use `resize` to add more than one.

Indexing out of bounds is undefined behavior. Which can result in a crash of your program in one of the better cases or result in you application being hijacked by malicious input.

Comment: ...or even seemingly work fine, *until it doesn't*, making for a very rude awakening months or years down the line.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `emplace` (and also `push_back`) add a new element into the vector, while the subscript operator gives access to an element that must already exist in the vector.

They do conceptually different things, so there is little point in comparing whether one is faster than the other.

P.S. If you access the vector out of bounds (such as `vec[0]` when the vector is empty), then the behaviour of the program is undefined. That is a bad thing.